# How is MySQL upgrade happening in the LTS 14.04 -> 16.04 upgrade?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, mysql, do-release-upgrade

When doing the LTS upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, how is MySQL updated, is a it just an in-place upgrade from Mysql 5.5 to 5.7? Or is there something fancier going on behind the scenes, like a logical dump that's dumped and loaded back in?

The reason I ask is I'm trying to do a clean install of 16.04 and I'm wondering how to migrate my MySQL data... (all the MySQL docs say do 5.5 -> 5.6 -> 5.7 but just wondering if its necessary)

Comment: "how to migrate my MySQL data" ...  Use the `mysql` commandline method to upload the last backup you made.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is done in-place, with some conversion needed and taken care of automatically. This is essentially about date conversion formats, if I remember well.  Watch out that some software have it difficult with MySQL 5.7.  For instance, Bacula versions earlier than 7.4.2 won't start.

Answer (score 0):

You asked: "*I'm wondering how to migrate my MySQL data..*"  You also propose to do a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04.

The approach I would suggest would be to backup ALL your MySQL data with [mysqldump](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/mysqldump.1.html) before upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04. Save your backup on a USB drive or other device that will not be involved in your upgrade.

After backing up the data (to a different device), do a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04. Reload MySQL and all associated (LAMP) programs from scratch. Then import your MySQL data from your backup.

One reason that I would encourage this approach has to do with the upgrade of PHP from version 5 to version 7 (which is now the default version).